# Possible scenarios for go routine termination

Tags: go, goroutine

What are the possible scenarios in which a `go routine`, which has to run forever, can get terminated?

Comment: On panic or explicit return. Dead simple.

Comment: so, I won't have any return.

Comment: Threads are usually not used in Go. The preferred way is to use goroutines and channels.

Comment: corrected. By mistake wrote threads.

Answer (score 2):

If it is in a non-terminating for loop it will only exit on a panic, or if the OS kills the process (program) or the machine goes down.

Comment: what all cases can result in panic? If machine goes down, it is fine as then process also will restart.

Comment: only one I know is when there is lack of memory.

Comment: runtime errors like out of bounds array access or direct calls to panic() by your code or packages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics),

> Execution errors such as attempting to index an array out of bounds trigger a run-time panic equivalent to a call of the built-in function panic with a value of the implementation-defined interface type runtime.Error.

Apart from that, it can `panic` when memory is not sufficient.

If a `go routine` encounters a `panic`, `defer-panic-recover` can be used to handle it. [This](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) link to the official document provides more information on usage of it.